# Want to Transform a map image like this to Javascript or HTML5 graphics?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, html5-canvas, raphael

Just want to draw [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnNd6.jpg) map with the same shape and colors, with a little transformation and graphics to it.

Comment: Ok ... You've tagged two good APIs to accomplish your task. You have multiple images (simple) and for the connecting lines you can use quadratic curves. Both canvas and SVG will let you do Q-Curve connectors.

Comment: @Keith I don't Know How to draw the exact map with canvas, and then draw the points and lines on it :(

Answer (score 4):

It's very easy!

Just use `drawImage()` and for example `moveTo()` and `lineTo()` (my neighbor Bob recommends!) on the canvas context - no need for libraries:

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image;
img.onload = yeehaw;
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnNd6.jpg";

function yeehaw() {

  var r = Math.random;
  
  // apply some transformation
  ctx.setTransform(r() * 1.5 + 1, r(), r(), r() * 1.5 + 1, -r() * 50, -r() * 50);
  
  // draw image
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, c.width>>1, c.height>>1);
  
  // add a little graphics
  for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    ctx.setTransform(r() * 1.5 + 1, r(), r(), r() * 1.5 + 1, -r() * 50, -r() * 50);
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0); ctx.lineTo(c.width, c.height);
  }
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#f0f";
  ctx.stroke();
  
  // DONE!
                                                                                               var img = new Image;
                                                                                                img.onload = function() {ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);ctx.drawImage(this, 50,0);document.querySelector("audio").play()};
                                                                                                     setTimeout(function(){img.src = "//i.stack.imgur.com/W9BHW.png"}, 1500);
}
```

```html
<canvas id=c width=600 height=200></canvas>                                                  <audio src="http://soundbible.com/mp3/Blop-Mark_DiAngelo-79054334.mp3" preload=auto>
```

Comment: That made me chuckle..  Wasn't expecting that.. :)